# Sensenet display UTC dates

Tags: sensenet

Here is an example for this issue:

I created a memo in the London demo workspace. I dated with today's date, but left the time blank.

After saving it, the default memo list view instead of today's date (June 2) showed yesterday's (June 1, 10PM). I suppose that system used two hour offset (GMT+1+1h Summer Savings Time) to deduct it from the date I entered.

What do I need to change in code (celltemplate?) to offset the date/time properly when displaying it?

Thanks